# how can i set tokeninput parameter on condition as dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I am using tokeninput jquery for autocomplete with asp.net.

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

i have one textbox and searching parameter is conditional. this jquery is render on loadtime. there is a checkbox, if checkbox is checked searching parameter wouldbe change and if checkbox is unchecked searching parameter is default parameter. i have called this on ready state.the issue is that when checkbox is checked searching parameter not changed. it search on only one condition as default condition.On ckeckbox click IsPastClass change as true  or false.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtStudentTokenSearch").tokenInput("../Handlers/TestAutoCompleteHandler.ashx?SearchType=Patient&IsPastClass=false", {
            theme: "facebook",
            tokenDelimiter: "|",
            preventDuplicates: true,
            onAdd: function(item) { removeTokenDuplicate('#txtStudentTokenSearch', item); btnLoadStudent.Focus(); }
        });
});
```

Can any one tell me how can i set tokeninput parameter on condition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkbox').change(function(){
        var IsPastClass = this.checked;
        $("#txtStudentTokenSearch").tokenInput("clear");
        $("#txtStudentTokenSearch").tokenInput("../Handlers/TestAutoCompleteHandler.ashx?SearchType=Patient&IsPastClass="+IsPastClass , {
            theme: "facebook",
            tokenDelimiter: "|",
            preventDuplicates: true,
            onAdd: function(item) { removeTokenDuplicate('#txtStudentTokenSearch', item); btnLoadStudent.Focus(); }
        });
    });
    $('.checkbox').trigger('change');
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for reply... it works but it create a new textbox.e.g i click on checkbox a new textbox is appear and old is also available...

Answer (score 0):

you can use tokenInput with ajax and handler very easly
you can download example from github
https://github.com/yanivsuzana/jquery-tokeninput-ajax-asp.net-vb